# read several csv files and same graphs for each csv in one plot

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, graph

I have a list of 12 csv files in one directory and I want to plot one of the colum in function of an other one, for each csv files and the 12 graphs should appear and save in one file. 
I have tried the following code that works for one csv file, but as soon as I set up the loop to read each file, it doesn't work.

```
library(lattice)
fichiers <- list.files(wd_envt_travail3, pattern=".csv")  
# wd_envt_travail3 = path where the files are

numfiles <- length(fichiers) 
df <- data.frame()

# i=2: test

# Reading of all the files
for(i in 1:numfiles){
   xx <- read.csv(as.character(fichiers[i]),sep=";")
   df <- rbind(df, xx)  
   xyplot(df$hauteur_epi_2 ~ df$hauteur_epi_1, df, xlim=c(0,15),ylim=c(0,15))
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Merge all CSVs into one data.frame `df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(fichiers,read.csv2))`, then plot.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! If I put the xyplot outside the loop then, indeed, it works with a unique plot including the data that have been merged, but actually I want 12 seperated graphs from the 12 csv files, so I am not sure I should merge the files. The operation of plotting is the same for all the csv files, that is why I am using a loop on the files, but it doesn't plot and save 12 graphs.

Comment: 1) Would saving as a pdf be ok? 2) Do you want one graph of 12 pages or 12 overlapped graphs?

Comment: Sorry, thought you wanted 1 plot output. To get 12 output plots for 12 CSV, add `pdf(paste0("file_",i,".pdf"))` before `xyplot`, then add `dev.off()` after `xyplot`.

Comment: @Fabio: 1) Yes a pdf is fine 2) 12 graphs on one page is what I would like.

Comment: @zx8754: Thank you. It is becoming closer to what I would like. Actually, 12 pdf files are created (but empty)... I removed df <- rbind(df, xx) and kept only xx. Then xyplot(xx$hauteur_epi_2 ~ xx$hauteur_epi_1, xx, xlim=c(0,15),ylim=c(0,15)), that I left inside the loop with dev.off () too. Still working on it, to have 12 graphs on 1pdf...Thanks again

Comment: Keep pdf() and dev.off() outside the loop, then we will have 1 pdf with 12 plots.

Comment: @ zx8754: It is not working, the pdf file doesn't fill in with the plot...either inside the loop, either outside the loop. I have now this code: `
library(lattice)
fichiers <- list.files(wd_envt_travail3, pattern=".csv")
numfiles <- length(fichiers) 
df <- data.frame()
  for(i in 1:numfiles){
    xx <- read.csv(as.character(fichiers[i]),sep=";")
    pdf(paste0("file_",i,".pdf")) 
    xyplot(xx$hauteur_epi_2 ~ xx$hauteur_epi_1, xx,  xlim=c(0,15),ylim=c(0,15))    
    dev.off()
  }
`